# AWS CLI command to get list of ec2 instances filtered according to no. of alarms attached

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I have to delete the some redundant alarms attached to the EC2 instances. For that I need to filter those EC2 instances which have more than 2 alarms attached. But I am not finding any filter provided by AWS through which I can filter the instances based on the attached alarms.
Also, describing alarms command would not help here as to every instance a unique alarm is attached.

Comment: alarms are not attached to instances, alarms monitor metrics which are populated from / by the instances / the ec2 service. I would say you need to get all the alarms, figure out what metrics they are based on and go from there. I would suggest e.g. python with boto3 for that instead of relying on the CLI and bash programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give a list with all ec2 instances defined in CW alarms dimensions in your account (equivalent to inaccurate term of attached):

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --query 'MetricAlarms[*].Dimensions[?(Name==`InstanceId`)].Value' --output text | sort
```

The `sort` will give you the list ordered, so any repeated instanceId, that means it has more than 1 alarm.